# Related boolean columns -- separate columns or bitpacked into an integer column?

Tags: sql, database-design, boolean

Hello I have a database for a certain record where it needs to store a 1 or a 0 for each day of the week. So which one would be better? Bitshifting each bit into an integer and just having an integer in the database named `days` or should we make all of them separate boolean values so to have `sunday, monday, tuesday...` columns?

Note that these columns are only used for a computation in our software(not on the DB itself) so the only thing that will be done with these values is selecting, updating, and inserting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for **separate columns**, for the following reasons:

- That would seem like the better-designed database model (because clearer, more intuitive, easier-to-understand), and everyone will probably not need any further explanations;
- "Which bit was for Sunday again...? Did I assign the most-significant bit to it, or the least-significant one?" -- You won't run into such problems with separate, named columns... therefore less potential for bugs.
- If you later want to enhance your database model so that you could store `NULL` for single days, you will almost definitely want a separate column per day. Otherwise, you'd need at least two bits per day (since you now have 3 possible states, and 1 bit no longer suffices for that) and an appropriate, home-baked encoding scheme.
- I'm quite sure today's RDBMSs are smart enough to pack several boolean columns together;

Answer (score 2):

Separate columns.

The DB engine will pack them anyway and work with the bits transparently for you. I suspect it's better at this than you or me rolling our own...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.  Sql Server suffers slower performance when querying with bitshifting.  If you'll be doing a lot of filtering for just one day per query, then I'd recommend separate bit fields for each day.

Comment: Can you back this up, or do you assume you can do better than MS engineers?